# EntityManager doesn't merge object to database

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a java spring application and use JPA

JPA initialization code

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class Application {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database");
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("pass");
    dataSource.setInitialSize(20);
    dataSource.setMaxActive(30);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
    lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    lef.setPackagesToScan("repository");
    return lef;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
}
```

}

I also have simple Entity object

```
@Entity
public class Client {
@Id
private int id;
private String name;
private String email;
private String phone;

public Client(){};

public Client(int id, String name, String email, String phone){
   this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    this.email=email;
    this.phone=phone;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
```

}

and Repository

```
@Repository
public class ProductRepository {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

@Transactional
public void saveClient() {
Client cl = new Client(1,"Alex","alex@gmail.com","1111111111");
em.merge(cl);

    }
}
```

When I call this method directly from controller I don't get data merged to database

```
@Controller
@ComponentScan("repository")
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

@Autowired
ProductRepository productRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home() {
productRepository.saveClient();  
return "home";
    }
}
```

I don't get any compilation or runtime exceptions and errors but merge doesn't result my object to be saved

Comment: hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true); 
change true and show generated query by hibernate and post here

Comment: looks strange ((   Hibernate: select client0_.id as id1_0_0_, client0_.email as email2_0_0_, client0_.name as name3_0_0_, client0_.phone as phone4_0_0_ from Client client0_ where client0_.id=?

Comment: Do you have a transaction manager configured?

Comment: already done. doesn't help

Comment: @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
    }

Comment: Ok now you can see that select statement is being issued because you're calling `EntityManager#merge` method. but you don't see `insert into ...` statement after that. Does that mean you already have a record in DB?

Comment: nope. the table is empty

Comment: It performs select instead of insert...

Comment: May be you can try with `EntityManager#persist` method to see what happens

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="..." /> use this servlet.xml and scan controller package and also add datasouce beans cofigration xml file and scan service package

Comment: persist does nothing as well ((

Comment: xml component scan of all packages didn't help. still performs select instread of insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application {}
```

instead of

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class Application {}
```

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

Comment: but good news from Hibernate )) Hibernate: insert into Client (email, name, phone) values (?, ?, ?)

Comment: even 2 queries Hibernate: select client0_.id as id1_0_0_, client0_.email as email2_0_0_, client0_.name as name3_0_0_, client0_.phone as phone4_0_0_ from Client client0_ where client0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into Client (email, name, phone) values (?, ?, ?)

Comment: anotate @GeneratedValue also id in Client class

Comment: unfortunatelly doesn't help

Comment: type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement ....

Comment: I have lot's of dependencies in pom.xml. can that be a reason?

Comment: not this eror is cause by your database schema error

Comment: change client.java class id integer to long

Comment: and recreate databashe schema make hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is update

Comment: then please confirim my answer